# is there any simple library for producing pdf from text file in python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, module

I am newbie here. How to generate whole text file into pdf using python. Is there any sample code? After search on Google, I only find pdf to text converter module. My python version is 2.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[reportlab](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) is the traditional Python pdf solution.

Comment: Thanks @Ned Deily, now I am using reportLab and succesfuly produce nice report in pdf.